# Why do the dictionaries in my list have the same contents after I read user input into each of them?

Tags: python

so I'm trying to get information from the user , asking him to enter his name and his age and store the values in a dictionary , each dictionary is put inside a table T
once the user finishes it shows all dictionaries have the same values for a reason that I don't know

```
T=[dict()]*3
for i in range(3):
   T[i]["Name"] = input('Enter name')
   T[i]["Age"] = int(input('Enter age'))
print(T)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] so that you can ask better questions going forward. Here, my objection is that the *question you are asking* is about a *problem* wherein the dicts have the same contents. Since they have *some* contents, clearly you are able to "get input for dictionaries", so that isn't the right thing to say in the question title - I have retitled it. You may also want to read ["How much research is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
T=[dict()]*3
```

What's happening is that a `dict` is created, put in a list and that list is then replicated three times as a single list - containing three references to the same dict. It's similar to:

```
d = dict()
T = [d]
for __ in range(2):
   T.extend(T)
```

You could instead:

```
T = [dict() for __ in range(3)]
```

This creates a list with three separate dicts.

By the way, you shouldn't name variables with capital letters in Python, to avoid confusion with class names - `t` would be a better name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
T=[dict() for _ in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
   T[i]["Name"] = input('Enter name')
   T[i]["Age"] = int(input('Enter age'))
print(T)
```